# Passing a Set[List[Int]] typed value instead of List[Int] - why does that work?

Tags: scala, types, signature

I have difficulties to understand the following when I look at the signatures and the function calls.

In my worksheet I have the following (taken from a Coursera lecture):

```
 object nqueens {

  def queens(n: Int) : Set[List[Int]] = {
    def placeQueens(k: Int) : Set[List[Int]] =
      if (k == 0) Set(List())
      else
      for  {
        queens <- placeQueens(k - 1)
        col <- 0 until n
        if isSafe(col, queens)
      } yield col :: queens
    placeQueens(n)
  }

  def isSafe(col: Int, queens: List[Int]) : Boolean = {
    val row = queens.length
    val queensWithRow = (row - 1 to 0 by -1) zip queens
    queensWithRow forall {
      case (r, c) => col != c && math.abs(col - c) != row -r
    }
  }

  def show(queens: List[Int]) = {
    val lines =
      for (col <- queens.reverse)
        yield Vector.fill(queens.length)("* ").updated(col, "X ").mkString
    "\n" + (lines mkString "\n")
  }

  (queens(4) map show) mkString "\n"

}
```

Considering the signatures of `placeQueen` and `isSafe`:

```
def placeQueens(k: Int) : Set[List[Int]]

def isSafe(col: Int, queens: List[Int]) : Boolean
```

I wonder why it works. We call `placeQueens` and save the result in `queens` (in the `for` loop).

The result should be of type `Set[List[Int]]`. Then we call `isSafe` with two parameters of `Int` and `Set[List[Int]]` - but I don't see why that works because `queens` should be of type `Set[List[Int]]` and the parameter for `isSafe` should `List[Int]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We call placeQueens and save the result in queens

Your code is not saving the result of `placeQueens` into `queens`.

```
for  {
    queens <- placeQueens(k - 1)
    col <- 0 until n
    if isSafe(col, queens)
  } yield col :: queens
```

This code is actually using for comprehension. The particular line in  question:

```
queens <- placeQueens(k-1)
```

is storing a `List[Int]` into queens, since it is iterating over the `Set[List[Int]]` returned from `placeQueens`. To give a simpler example that might help illustrate what's going on, consider:

```
val a = Set(1,2,3)
val b = for (x <- a) yield x + 2
```

After executing this code, `b` will be `Set(3,4,5)`. This is because at each iteration in the for loop, `x` is first 1, then 2, then 3.

Answer (score 2):

> We call `placeQueens` and save the result in `queens` (in the for loop).

No, you're calling `placeQueens` and iterating over the result. At each iteration `queens` refers to the current element.